# mysql - select multiple colums value from two table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select post content and images for a given post.

I have a `post` and `image` tables and I want to select some/not all columns from both based on `postid`.

I am doing this way but getting syntax error.

```
SELECT `title`,`desc`,`date`, FROM `img`.`post` 
INNER JOIN 

    (SELECT `hash`,`hits`,`timestamp`,`userid` FROM `img`.`image` WHERE `postid` IS NOT NULL)

WHERE `postid` IS NOT NULL
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do it.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: what is the common attribute in both the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `,` before table name

```
 SELECT `title`,`desc`,`date`,
```

You need to create alias of your table

```
SELECT `title`,`desc`,`date` FROM `img`.`post` 
INNER JOIN 

    (SELECT `hash`,`hits`,`timestamp`,`userid`,`postid` FROM `img`.`image` WHERE `postid` IS NOT NULL) 

AS a

WHERE a.`postid` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: now i am getting `( ! ) Fatal error: Every derived table must have its own alias in`

Comment: I am getting Unknown column a.`postid`

Comment: you need to add `postid` in your select statement!! check updated

Comment: HI, how can I get result from sub-query `a` in prepaid statement

Comment: i does't understand your prolem

Comment: I am getting result for `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($prepare, $title,$desc,$date);` not for `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($prepare, $title,$desc,$date,$hash,$hits,$timestamp,$userid,$postid);` this gives error as no of bind variable do not match. PS: no of image in a post differ from post to post.

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT `p.title`,`p.desc`,`p.date`,`im.hash`,`im.hits`,`im.timestamp`,`im.userid` FROM `post` as p 
    INNER JOIN `image` as im ON p.postid =im.postid
```

If you are using inner join then u dont have to use is not null condition since it will return only matching values